# Login with passing token

Tags: android, json, authentication

I have JSON like this

```
{
"data": {
    "id": x,
    "username": "xx",
    "name": "xx",
    "email": "xxxx@xxx.xxx",
    "gender": "xxx",
    "place": "xxxxx",
    "date": "xx/xx/xxxx",
    "religion": "xxxxx",
    "address": "xxxx",
    "telp": "xxxxxxx",
    "photo": null
},
"meta": {
    "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
}
```

I want to make login and register in my Android Studio with that API. How can I pass that token to headers like in postman? thank you

Comment: your are using volley or some thing else ?

Comment: What is that JSON? is that format your API is expecting?

Comment: @JayThummar I am using JSON Parser, but I don't know how to put that token to headers

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yeah, I mean that is JSON

Comment: so you want to extract a token from it, and use that token in header?

Comment: I already get the token, just use it into the headers @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: ok, which classes you use to make requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpPost postwithHeader = new HttpPost(YOUR URL);
postwithHeader.addHeader( "token" , "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" );
```